# Django Model ImageField upload_to won't take a function as argument

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to rename my a image when its uploaded. I can't seem to get it to work.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=photo_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def photo_file_name(self, filename):
        extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = 'cover_photo_{}.{}'.format(self.id, extension)
        return os.path.join('articles/media/articles/photos/coverphotos/', filename)
```

None of the answers have been able to help me. I get a NameError: name 'photo_file_name' is not defined. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you model add this,

```
import os
from uuid import uuid4
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible


@deconstructible
class PathAndRename(object):
   def __init__(self, sub_path):
       self.path = sub_path

   def __call__(self, instance, filename):
       # add extension as per your requirement, I am using .png
       ext = "png"
       # set filename as random string
       filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
       # return the whole path to the file
       return os.path.join(self.path, filename)

class Article(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=PathAndRename('images/'), blank=True, null=True)
```

clear your photo file name function. You can add PathAndRename to all your model.

Answer (score 1):

hi function should not be part of the class

```
def photo_file_name(self, filename):
    extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = 'cover_photo_{}.{}'.format(self.id, extension)
    return os.path.join('articles/media/articles/photos/coverphotos/', filename)


class Article(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=photo_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   description = models.TextField()
   url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That worked! But how do I access the model's id that its associated with.

Comment: I want to append the id of the model to the name of the file.